# Can credit card tokens be used across different accounts within Edge Express or OpenEdge?

Tags: token

Can credit card tokens be used across different accounts within Edge Express or OpenEdge? Or

Is it possible to utilize credit card tokens across distinct accounts within Edge Express or OpenEdge?

I authorized a card using an OpenEdge merchant account, obtained a token associated with that account, and attempted to use the same token for a sale transaction with a different merchant account under OpenEdge.

Expecting to utilize same card token with different merchant account of openedge like a cross token work